# how to read anything after EOF has occured

Tags: c

I was studing the c programming book of k & r. There is this program to count no of characters in input

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
long nc;
nc=0;
while(getchar()!=EOF)
     ++nc;
printf("%ld\n",nc);
}
```

I was wondering how come after EOF has occured nc can be printed. Is there any way to it.

Answer (score 2):

The end-of-file condition only affects `stdin`, not `stdout`.  Note that there are no uses of `stdin` after the `EOF` is found, just printouts to `stdout`.

Comment: i completely understand that they are both different stream input and output. but the thing is when i run this program. its like an infinite loop and when i press (ctrl+z  i.e EOF) it terminates without printing nc(i.e running printf line)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting two different things mixed up. EOF is with regard to input. printf is an output function.

Comment: i completely understand that they are both different stream input and output. but the thing is when i run this program. its like an infinite loop and when i press (ctrl+z  i.e EOF) it terminates without printing nc(i.e running printf line)

Answer (score 0):

getchar() reads from stdin. printf() writes to stdout. They are different streams that usually map to the same physical device (console or terminal).

Comment: i completely understand that they are both different stream input and output. but the thing is when i run this program. its like an infinite loop and when i press (ctrl+z  i.e EOF) it terminates without printing nc(i.e running printf line)

Answer (score 0):

You should not count on a Ctrl-Z or any terminator
If you were counting on that and were running on traditional *nix shells you would suspend your process rather than terminate the input (read up on JOB CONTROL, in `man bash`, for example)

(I know this answer comes a bit late but I see you keep mentioning Ctrl-Z in you responses to other answers)

If you are on a *nix system you can use Ctrl-D, but dont expect that to end up in your input stream (its just used as a signaling mechanism).m   You can also test this with a file input which should give you more consistent results than typing, i.e.

```
a.out < prog.c
```

to count the lines in your c program